# Journey History status - Failed

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

In my journey I can see around 500 subscriber not received the email when I debug in the journey  history I can see all this contacts status marked as **failed** and activity is **Other**.

May I know what is the reason for this and how to debug this issue.

Appreciate[image] your help